# Rails app fails to deploy when upgrading elastic beanstalk stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am upgrading my elastic beanstalk version to Puma with Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.11.8 via elb's ui. When I do so I get this error. It works if I revert back to platform version 2.11.4

```
Initialization failed at 2020-08-07T04:41:35Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/preinit/22_gems.sh failed.

++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir
+ EB_SCRIPT_DIR=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts
++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k gem_dir
+ EB_GEM_DIR=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/gems/puma
+ . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/use-app-ruby.sh
++ . /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
+++ CHRUBY_VERSION=0.3.9
+++ RUBIES=()
+++ for dir in '"$PREFIX/opt/rubies"' '"$HOME/.rubies"'
+++ [[ -d /opt/rubies ]]
++++ ls -A /opt/rubies
+++ [[ -n ruby-1.9.3-p551
ruby-2.0.0-p648
ruby-2.1.10
ruby-2.2.10
ruby-2.3.8
ruby-2.4.9
ruby-2.5.7
ruby-2.6.5
ruby-current ]]
+++ RUBIES+=("$dir"/*)
+++ for dir in '"$PREFIX/opt/rubies"' '"$HOME/.rubies"'
+++ [[ -d /.rubies ]]
+++ unset dir
+++ cat /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.ruby_version
++ chruby 2.6.6
++ case "$1" in
++ local dir match
++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551
++ case "${dir##*/}" in
++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648
++ case "${dir##*/}" in
++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.10
++ case "${dir##*/}" in
++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.10
++ case "${dir##*/}" in
++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8
++ case "${dir##*/}" in
++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.9
++ case "${dir##*/}" in
++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7
++ case "${dir##*/}" in
++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5
++ case "${dir##*/}" in
++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-current
++ case "${dir##*/}" in
++ [[ -z '' ]]
++ echo 'chruby: unknown Ruby: 2.6.6'
chruby: unknown Ruby: 2.6.6
++ return 1.
Process default has been unhealthy for 34 minutes (Target.FailedHealthChecks).
```

How do I go about debugging this? The rails app is running on ruby 2.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a ruby in the available rubies (like 2.6.5) or figure out how to make other rubies available.